# Flickity not initializing properly when data comes from ReactiveVar

Tags: html, node.js, meteor, carousel, flickity

I'm using flickity with Meteor and I'm trying to make a carousel from an array that comes from a ReactiveVar, like so:

```
Template.quickAnalyse.onRendered(function() {
    this.autorun(() =>{
        if (Template.instance().configuredSites.get() != undefined) {
            console.log(Date.now());
            $('.index-carousel').flickity({
                cellAlign: 'center',
                contain: true,
                setGallerySize: false,
                groupCells: true
            });
        }
    });
});

Template.quickAnalyse.helpers({
    getConfiguredSites() {
        console.log(Template.instance().configuredSites.get());
        console.log(Date.now());
        return Template.instance().configuredSites.get();
    },
});
```

The `console.log(Date.now())` tells me that the `getConfiguredSites()` helper is running before the carousel initialization, so it should work.

The problem is that my carousel cells aren't rendered in the`flickity-viewport`.

It looks like this : https://postimg.cc/s1tF07mP

However, when I'm returning the datas like this :

```
Template.quickAnalyse.helpers({
    getConfiguredSites() {
        console.log(Template.instance().configuredSites.get());
        console.log(Date.now());
        return [{site: "1", installation: "1", batiment: "1"}, {site: "2", installation: "2", batiment: "2"}, {site: "3", installation: "3", batiment: "3"}]
    },
});
```

Here is the result : https://postimg.cc/vgZzzqCY

First I thought that the time between the helper and the initialization, int the first case, was to short but it's even shorter in the second case and it's working. So the problem probably comes from somewhere else but I can't figure it out.

The only thing that comes in my mind is that, maybe, the `Template.instance().configuredSites.get()` takes to long.

How could I solve that problem ?

Thanks.

EDIT: After testing my last theory, like that:

```
{{#each getConfiguredSites}}
    {{showTime}}
    <div class="carousel-cell">
        <div class="card index-card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>{{this.site}}</p>
                <p>{{this.installation}}</p>
                <p>{{this.batiment}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

and

```
showTime() {
    console.log(Date.now());
}
```

The `console.log(Date.now())` from the `onRendered` appears before the `showTime`'s one... How could I solve that without adding an ugly `setTimeout()` in my `onRendered` ?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem.

Asking the question here made me ask myself some other questions and here is the final solution :

```
{{#with getConfiguredSites}}
    {{#each this}}
        <div class="carousel-cell col-xl-2">
            <div class="card index-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>{{this.site}}</p>
                    <p>{{this.installation}}</p>
                    <p>{{this.batiment}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{#if isLast .. @index}}
            {{initializeCarousel}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

```
Template.quickAnalyse.onRendered(function() {
    this.autorun(() => {
        if (Template.instance().readyForCarousel.get() === true) {
            $('.index-carousel').flickity({
                cellAlign: 'center',
                contain: true,
                setGallerySize: false,
                groupCells: true
            });
        }
    });
});

Template.quickAnalyse.helpers({
    getConfiguredSites() {
        return Template.instance().configuredSites.get();
    },

    isLast(data, index) {
        if (index + 1 == data.length)
            return true;
        return false;
    },

    initializeCarousel() {
        Template.instance().readyForCarousel.set(true);
    }
});
```

I hope it'll help someone else :)